# WIndows 8.1 doesn't take the right favicon to create the tile

Tags: windows, favicon

I have created some favicons using realfavicongenerator and I have checked them with the same page. Everything looks right, but when I add a tile in Windows 8.1, it takes another favicon and uses a default tile color.

My code:

```
<!-- Touch Icons - iOS and Android 2.1+ 180x180 pixels in size. --> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="resources/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<!-- Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 192x192 pixels in size. -->
<link rel="icon" href="resources/favicons/favicon.png">
<!-- Android Chrome M39+ -->
<link rel="manifest" href="resources/favicons/manifest.json">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#2d89ef">
<!-- Windows 8 / IE 10 -->
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2d89ef">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="resources/favicons/mstile-144x144.png">
<!-- Windows 8 / IE 11 -->
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="resources/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
```

Furthermore, I have favicon.ico in the root.

Browserconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="resources/favicons/mstile-70x70.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="resources/favicons/mstile-150x150.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="resources/favicons/mstile-310x310.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="resources/favicons/mstile-310x150.png"/>
      <TileColor>#2d89ef</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

I have also tried with all the content in the root (with the right paths), but nothing changes.

For Windows 8.1 I'm using the white silhouette option with a blue tile. But what I get is the favicon that is shown in the browser with the default tile color.

Comment: As the author of RFG, I congratulate you for this excellent choice! :) When you test tiles, make sure to use IE 11 and Win 8.1 *RT* (eg. on a Microsoft Surface). IE 11 doesn't use the tiles on classic Windows. If your web site is public, can you give me the URL for review? Also, you can run the compatibility test (http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test) to understand which icon is used instead of the tiles.

Comment: My site is on development phase. The compatibility test says that is OK. But I have realized that I was testing on Windows 8.1, not Windows 8.1 RT. I suposse that there is not way to say to Windows 8.1 to take the defined tiles, do it?

Comment: That's right, you really need an RT version. Two years ago, I went to a store in order to test tiles on a Surface :)

Comment: Thanks. The reference to Windows 8.1/IE 11 instead of Windows 8.1 RT/IE 11 confused me.